Getting JIT compilation of template error while creating dynamic angular HTML
Getting JIT compilation of template error while creating dynamic angular HTML, refer the below screenshot. Angular HTML code not resolving.

Here is the stackblitz code:
Steps to reproduce:

Click on HTML Template button then click on Render Template Button (plain HTML) - working scenario

Click on Angular Template button then click on Render Template Button (angular code - ex: [ngSTyle]) - JIT compilation error scenario


Getting JIT compilation error while click on Render Template Button for Angular Template Code

I wonder, what is the use case for ngStyle? Because in the demo, only the template can be defined... So I don't really see how this would be useful.

Hello Derulo, I want to resolve angular directives and attributes (*ngIf, ngStyle, ngClass), dynamically by applying the behavior to the template based on the values defined.

You are trying to use the ngStyle for static css in the below line
  template2() {
const template = `<div [style.--color]="'30' > '35' ? '#FF9900': 'blue'">
<div style="--percentage : 30;height: 55px; width: 55px;
  background-color: #555;border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(var(--color) calc(1%*var(--percentage)),white 0%);"></div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="percentage == 30" [style.--color]="percentage === 30 ? 'green' : 'blue'">Angular TEMPLATE</div>`;
this.txtAreaRef.nativeElement.value = template;

}

Thanks for response. I am trying to use below angular html code to resolve, but its not resolving. Updated the stackblitz code, please help me here.
Angular TEMPLATE
I have edited the code in the above comment, Please check

Hello Viji, I want to resolve angular directives and attributes (*ngIf, ngStyle, ngClass), dynamically by applying the behavior to the template based on the values defined.
